# ListPopupWindow - gives error in asyncTask

Tags: android, user-interface

The method below crashes when run in doInBackground method, but works fine in activity.

```
private void showPopup(ArrayList<String> dates) {
    ListPopupWindow popup = new ListPopupWindow(context);
    popup.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dates
                    .toArray(new String[dates.size()])));

    popup.setAnchorView(context.periodicTable);
    popup.setWidth(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked item " + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            context.startProgressDialog();
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: sorry you do in background is not a ui thread to handle ui operations you can use run on ui thread to call the method from doin background

Comment: but runOnUiThread() did not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to manipulate the UI from a background thread.

You should only do this from your UI thread.